# Laravel8 image from database

Tags: php, laravel

There are 2 different projects, the 1st is the admin dashboard, the other is the webpage itself. If you upload a picture through the admin dashboard into the database, that is saved as a blob file. How the photo in the database can be displayed in the webpage project?

Comment: Storing files in databases is quite an outdated method. Are you sure it's necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload file in your project's upload folder and save that file's name in your database then that way you can access files stored in your project's upload folder from database record

That way most of the web apps manage files of the project, upload files in project directory and store it's url in the database